# Eclipse Maven Project import compiler-plugin:2.3.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-8, maven-3, m2eclipse

Using jdk8, Maven 3.3.3, Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0).

Trying to import a Maven project into eclipse (Import 'existing Maven project'). Getting error: `CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`

Have tried to install this plugin- whatever I tried 'Install New Software"- did not work. 
Tried adding a couple of M2E connectors also. I now have:

m2e connector for maven-remote-resources-plugin
m2e connector for the Maven Dependency Plugin

How to solve this?  Thanks

Comment: the problem *is right there*, can't you see it? Failed to transfer...

Comment: @Eugene Cant get your point, Failed to transfer- but why?

Comment: numerous reasons, may be maven central on that node is down, may be you hit a timeout, etc.

Comment: I have tried it many times- always same result- it happens quickly - so my guess is - likely is not timeout. Could be Gateway issues - don't know. But totally stumped/stuck for now

Comment: It is not my network issue. Tried it in a couple of other networks (incl Sbux) - exact same error. I dont' have settings.xml (at least could not find it) - so what else can be done to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this by maven cli- `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Then I was able to import the project into eclipse. 
Before that I tried other maven cli commands: `mvn clean install`, `package`, etc - none worked.
So one more painful saga endured